# Change color for each item in itemize

Tags: macros, color, itemize

Consider the following simple code:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\begin{document}        
\begin{itemize}
    \item plain text
    \item I want this to be blue
    \item another text
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The result of the code is

[image]

Now, suppose that I want to make the text color of the second item blue. One can manually use the `textcolor` command, but the thing is that in my real example there are many places to change the text, and such places are frequently modified. Hence, it is desirable to write a macro to change the color simply.

**Question**: How can I define custom command like `\blueitem`, such that replacing `\item` to `\blueitem` in the above code gives the desired result? Or, as an alternative, one can also think of a macro that using `\item[color=blue]` instead of `\item` gives the result.

**Edit**: The answer by Sandy G does not work when used with the `proof` environment. For example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\let\olditem\item\renewcommand{\item}[1][black]{\color{#1}\olditem} 
\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
    \item[blue] abc
    \begin{proof}
        abc.
    \end{proof}
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

This code gives an error message

```
Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `\hskip \labelsep \itshape Proof\relax '. a
```

and the result is:

[image]

Note that there is no "Proof." symbol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can redefine `\item` to accept an optional argument for the color using `xcolor`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\usepackage{xcolor}

\let\olditem\item\renewcommand{\item}[1][black]{\color{#1}\olditem}

\begin{document}        
\begin{itemize}
    \item plain text
    \item[blue] I want this to be blue
    \item[red] another text
    \item one more
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

The main problem with this approach is that some environments use lists, and there are undesired consequences. Notably, a `proof` from `amsthm` is a list, so this won't work. A better solution is to make a new command, for example `\citem` that accepts an optional color argument:

`\newcommand{\citem}[1][black]{\color{#1}\item}`

[image]

One downside to this approach is that `\citem` will change the color of all `\item`s below it in the list. So use `\citem` with no color (black is the default) to change back to black for the rest of the list. Then you can use `\item` and `\citem` in the same list.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\newcommand{\citem}[1][black]{\color{#1}\item} 
\begin{document}

\begin{itemize}
  \citem[blue] abc
    \begin{proof}
        abc.
    \end{proof}
  \citem[red] abc
    \begin{proof}
        abc.
    \end{proof}
    
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Sadly, when `\item` is used together with the `proof` environment, there seems a problem (please see my edited post). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: My suggestion/method works with proof environment also. Only thing as noted is to put the stuff between braces.

Comment: @eigenvalue: I updated my solution so it works with `proof`.

Comment: +1 but may I suggest something along the lines of `\renewcommand{\item}[1][black]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\color{black}\else\color{#1}\fi\olditem}`? In this way you can use the "second" optional argument by leaving the first one empty.

Comment: @campa: This is a good idea, but still has problems interacting with `proof`, so probably better to do this with the second solution: `\newcommand{\citem}[1][black]{\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\color{black}\else\color{#1}\fi\item}`

Comment: @Sandy G. With your code, by copying the definition of the environment proof from amsthdoc p.11 by replacing \item by \citem we have the proof in black. It's not ideal, but maybe it's okay.

Answer (score 2):

This is one way to do it:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}                                                     
\usepackage{xcolor}                                                               
                                                                                  
\newcommand\colitem[2]{%                                                          
  {\color{#1}\item {#2}}                                                          
}                                                                                 
                                                                                  
\newcommand\reditem[1]{%                                                          
  \colitem{red}{#1}                                                               
}                                                                                 
                                                                                  
\newcommand\blueitem[1]{%                                                         
  \colitem{blue}{#1}                                                              
}                                                                                 
                                                                                  
\begin{document}                                                                  
\begin{itemize}                                                                   
    \reditem {plain text}                                                         
    \blueitem {I want this to be blue}                                            
    \item another text                                                            
\end{itemize}                                                                     
\end{document}
```

The output will be like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. However, one sad thing is that I need parenthesis `{...}` in `\blueitem {I want this to be blue}`  to make this work. Is there way to use this command without using the parenthesis?

Comment: Yes. I could not find a way to do it. Someone more knowledgeable will help you.